# Computed timestamps in EF Core entity backed by Postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm using EF Core v5 and the Npgsql EF Core provider v5 for Postgres v14.

I want `CreatedAt` and `UpdatedAt` computed columns to be set automatically. They are both of type `DateTime`.

I tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=fluent-api):

```cs
builder
  .Property(x => x.CreatedAt)
  .IsRequired()
  .HasDefaultValueSql("timestamp with time zone");

builder
  .Property(x => x.UpdatedAt)
  .IsRequired()
  .HasComputedColumnSql("timestamp with time zone", stored: true);
```

But that throws when creating the table (`Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42601: syntax error at or near ")"`).

If I remove the code above then everything works, so the problem is isolated to that code.

I think `timestamp with time zone` is correct for UTC [timestamps](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-datetime.html), but the overall syntax is obviously wrong. How do I fix it?

Comment: Cross-posted on github and answered there: https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/2079

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timestamp with time zone` is a Postgresql type name rather than a value. The value of the current timestamp with time zone is `current_timestamp` or `now()`. Try

```
.HasDefaultValueSql("now()");
```

Comment: Thanks! Note though that it fails with `Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P17: generation expression is not immutable`. I'm also trying to use the standard sql syntax shown [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT), and `now()` is considered "non-standard". But you confirmed that my syntax was completely wrong, so thank you for that.

Comment: Oh, `now()` is Postgresql specific. Pls. try `current_timestamp` instead of `now()`. It is sematically the same but SQL standard.

Comment: That gives the same exception... I think there is some magic ingredient that I'm missing somewhere. You are right I was using the data type as a value, and the value you gave me is probably correct. But the EF provider is expecting something more... not sure what though. Thanks again.

Comment: Who is generating the error, HasComputedColumnSql or HasDefaultValueSql? You certainly can not use a volatile expression in a stored calculated column..

Comment: You are right, it was `HasComputedColumnSql` that was throwing. But there must be a way to do it, because for example I can use `HasComputedColumnSql("getutcdate()")` for SQL Server.

Comment: Well, this is not the case in Postgresql. [(details)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html). Use a view if you need a volatile generated column.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
.HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
```

Comment: Thanks. It's the same as the other answer, and it causes exceptions unfortunately, when the db is created.

Comment: You can't specify a mutable statement inside HasComputedColumnSql in Postgres. If you wish to update the field on UPDATE you have to use a Trigger.

Comment: Yes that seems to be the case, unfortunately. Thanks for confirming.